# Crystal Report XI- Suppressing Header after page break

Tags: header, crystal-reports-xi, page-break, suppress

Hi I'm new to using Crystal Report XI and I'm having a difficult time with this issue.

I run a billing statement using Crystal Report Monthly. And I process at least a thousand statements on one PDF. The header ie: "DB---Break" tells our system when a participant statement ends and a new statement begins (Mailing Purposes).

However, if a participant has an overflow of statements that goes onto the the next page. The header "DB--Break" cuts off that statement for that participant.

With all that being said, I'm currently trying to find a way to suppress the header on the second page of the participant who has a overflow of information. How would go about resolving this? Thanks in advance

Example:

DB----Break (Header)

Joe Smith, (Name)

TEXT TEXT TEXT (body)

--------Break in Page----------

DB--Break (Need to suppress this Header)

TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT (continuation of body from John Smith)

--------Break in Page----

DB----Break (Header)

Sarah Johnson, ( New Participant Begins)

TEXT TEXT TEXT (Body)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Right click on Header -> Select Section Expert.

Highlight the header you want to suppress. On the Common tab to the right check the supress checkbox

Then click on the formula x+2 button and enter the following formula:

**pagenumber > 1** and click on Save and Close.

This should suppress the header section on second page.